# A continuous open surjective map $f$ with compact fibers preserves Hausdorffness.

Tags: general-topology, open-map

Let $f:X\to Y$ be an open, surjective, continuous map between two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ with compact fibers. Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological space. Then $Y$ is Hausdorff.

I wanted to show that by taking two distinct points $a_1$ and $a_2$ in $Y$. If I take their compact fibers $B_1=f^{-1}(a_1)$ and $B_2=f^{-1}(a_2)$, then I can separate them by disjoint open subsets $U_1$ and $U_2$ where $B_i\subset U_i$ as $B_i$ is compact. However, I struggle to show that $f(U_1)$ and $f(U_2)$ are going to be disjoint. Am I doing something wrong, or is there another way to show that?

Comment: In the title you have the assertion of compact fibers but not in the body of the question.

Comment: Updated, but I mentioned compactness when I defined $B_i$.

Comment: You can show from these assumptions that $f$ is in fact "proper": $f^{-1}[K]$ is compact when $K \subseteq Y$ is compact. That might help some.

Comment: There is another question that has a Lemma that may be helpfull: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385996/if-every-image-under-a-continuous-open-map-of-a-hausdorff-space-is-hausdorff-sh

Comment: What is the source of your question? Are you sure that $f$ is required to be *open* and not to be *closed*?

Comment: @PaulFrost, I basically want to use that statement to show that $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ is Hausdorff by considering the quotient map $\pi: S^3 \to \mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$. I am not sure if that quotient map is closed.

Comment: I recommend to reformulate your question to "Does a continuous open surjective map $f$ with compact fibers preserve Hausdorffness?" I doubt that it is true in general, so perhaps somebody can give a counterexample. It is well-known that a continuous closed surjective map $f$ with compact fibers preserves Hausdorffness. Now look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3998245.

Comment: @PaulFrost, awesome! Thank you! Yeah, I suspected that as I did not see how I could proceed to show that.